# Is there a way to specify the width of the UIContextualAction in iOS11?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios11

In the UITableViewRowAction, the width of action could be manipulated by changing the title and putting in spaces. The more spaces you use, the wider area that your action would occupy on the row.

With the new UIContextualAction, putting spaces in the title doesn't do anything. The OS decides exactly how much space the action gets. I have a need to show 5 different action options and on smaller devices, I can no longer fit 5. Does anyone know of a way to control the size of each of these areas in the view?

```
func setupAction(_ indexVar: Int) -> UIContextualAction {
    let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "   ", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        //do something
        success(true)
    })
    editAction.image = UIImage(named: "TestImage")
    editAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return editAction
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems in iOS11 either image of a specific size or text only will be accepted for tableviewcell swipe.

Another option (which I do not recommend) is to add gesture to tableview.

Or adding gesture to tableviewcell; like, initially create a view in the custom cell and apply PanGestureRecognizer to this view in the cell. Add the buttons needed to the custom cell, when you swipe the view in the custom cell, the buttons in the custom cell shall be visible.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr**: Use any existing framework for this, or make your own, for now.

I have been dealing with this issue on iOS 11 for few days now. The best result I could get was by programmaticaly adding transparent space to the bottom of the image so it fills full height of the row. By this, and setting **clipsToBounds** to the cell, the title was positioned outside of the cell's view and invisible, and I could use any characters to increase width of action button, for example "XXXXX" string.

But there were some cases when the title was still visible, even when I set clipsToBounds. To minimize it's visibility I set it with spaces and dots at the edges, like **".(space)(space)(space)."**.

Finaly, as the title (composed of dots and spaces) was still visible, I have ended up with creating my own action buttons in tableViewCell.